# making smooth lined plots in python using yt toolkit

Tags: python, matplotlib, yt-project

I have been using python based yt toolkit to analyze some data and my files are not that frequent enough to make a smooth plot out of it. The plot is shown on a log scale.

```
        ni56Mass[n] = (d['cell_mass'] * d['ni56']).sum()


        plt.semilogy(time,ni56Mass,label='$^{56}$Ni')
        plt.xlabel('time [s]')
        plt.ylabel('fallback mass [$M_\odot$]')
        plt.xlim(20,60)
        plt.ylim(1.0e-3, 2.0e-1)
        plt.legend(loc=3)
```

an example output looks like the following [image]

I was wondering if there is a tool in either yt or python itself to make a smooth plot out of this data. Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use a cubic spline, e.g. from scipy: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html

Comment: You could also plot it as a scatter plot instead of a line plot.